# React Native Calendar List: today's date in every month is being marked without me passing those dates into markedDates parameter

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-calendars

For some reason I have this weird bug where today's date (ie the 14th) is highlighted in every future and past month. I never pass anything into my markedDates parameter that would tell the calendar to mark the xth of every month, so I was wondering if anyone has any idea why this could be happening or if this has happened to anyone else. Any tips would be appreciated.
TYIA

Answer (score 0):

Hlo,
I Don't know what is happening having same issue ,
But solved by change a line in node module
node_modules/react-native-calendars/src/calendar/day/basic/index.js

[Image_link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSx8I.png)

simple replace line 31 with 32 as shown in above image
please try

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work for me. What ended up working was following @TomCorvus's response on [this github issue](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars/issues/2073)

Answer (score 0):

As of now (07-feb-2023) this is an [Open issue](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars/issues/2073) in the react-native-calendars.
The easiest option is to downgrade with a few versions until collaborators fix it.

The problem was introduced after `1.1289.0` and the latest version is `1.1293.0`. so I didn't find any major difference between the two.

For me; changing today's background color also didn't work along with the above issue. downgrade fixed everything.
`{todayBackgroundColor: '#777', todayTextColor: '#000',}`

---

**Steps to downgrade**

1. replace your `"react-native-calendars": "^1.xxxx.x",` with `""react-native-calendars": "1.1289.0",` in your package.json
2. do a `npm install` or `yarn install`